# On c# how to save all words documents open? (not open from c# )

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, office-interop

For try this its necesary make these steps..

- 1.-Open Microsoft Word
- 2.-Write anything on this for example ("hello Word")
- 3.-on c# aplication this must to save the document opened on step 1 (this would be better which could be saved when document is not empty
  (for example if this has a letter then this would be saved))
- 4.- for N documents of Microsoft Word which is open, it must be saved when button is pressed. for example if on step 1. You open 3
  Microsoft
  Word and write ("hello word") on 3 documents, on step 3 must to be
  saved the 3 documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an instance of the running Word Application class using the System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject method. See [How to use Visual C# to automate a running instance of an Office program](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316126) for more information.

Then you can do whatever you need using the Word object model. See [How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316384) and [C# app automates Word (CSAutomateWord)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateWord-f422cae5).